# How do I prevent animated scrolling text from suddenly restarting in HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made this codepen to demonstrate what I am talking about: https://codepen.io/sakana-boy/pen/wvBedWo

```css
.scroll-text {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.scroll-text * {
    white-space: pre;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    animation: scroll 5s steps(70, end) infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% { transform: translateX(100%); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-text" style="width: 355px;">
  <div>hi i am very long text lolololololoololo this is very long sdafkalshgjalwke more text wow ok TOO LONG!!! you Will not See THIS text because it gets cut off : ( very sad </div>
</div>
<div class="scroll-text" style="width: 355px;">
  <div>this text is shorter so all the text properly is shown</div>
</div>
```

Basically, I have text that I plan on populating dynamically and I would like to scroll the text in a narrow parent div (than the text). As you can see in the above codepen, the scrolling suddenly restarts in the middle of the animation. I could set the 100% keyframe for translateX to have a higher (lower?) value, however since the text is dynamic, I can't know the value ahead of time. Additionally, if the value is too high, then shorter text has a long period of being blank in the textbox.

Is there a way to dynamically assign the keyframe 0% and 100% values so that I get the entire text to show up in the animation? The second line is how all the text should scroll (that is, showing all of the content before restarting). Also, I do not want to increase the width of the parent divs as it will cause the text to overflow into the other elements (in my real webpage).

If this is not possible with HTML and CSS alone, I am open to using Javascript (preferably vanilla JS so I don't need to include jQuery).

Comment: I would advice against using a scrolling text. It's hard to read, it will be almost impossible to make the scrolling smooth, and it's really intrusive conative speaking.

Comment: I don't want smooth scrolling text and I have a specific use case that I want this scrolling text for (I used step on purpose rather than linear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position: relative`, and `transform`:

- `transform: translateX(100%)` use 100% size of content (text);
- `position: relative; left: 100%`. use 100% size of container;

Use `display: table` so the inner `div` got a width fit its content.

```css
.scroll-text {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.scroll-text * {
    display: table;
    white-space: pre;
    position: relative;
    animation: scroll 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% { left: 100%; transform: translateX(0); }
  100% { left: 0; transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-text" style="width: 355px;">
  <div>hi i am very long text lolololololoololo this is very long sdafkalshgjalwke more text wow ok TOO LONG!!! you Will not See THIS text because it gets cut off : ( very sad </div>
</div>
<div class="scroll-text" style="width: 355px;">
  <div>this text is shorter so all the text properly is shown</div>
</div>
```